# how many unique $3$ digit numbers can be formed using digits $1,1,1,1,2$? Explain the logic too.

Tags: permutations, combinations, problem-solving, education

Only numbers
$111,112,121,211$ can be formed through these. How to get this mathematically
because for $1,1,1,1,1,2$ also the answer is same $111,112,121,211$ and so on as $1$'s increases answer remains same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continued from comments ...

The only possibilities are

$aaa$ for each number that we have three or more

$aab$ and permutations (whenever we have two or more $a$'s)

$abc$ and permutations (for all the digits or symbols available).

For each $aaa$ there is one permutation, for $aab$ three permutations, and for $abc$ six permutations.

Comment: yeah got it now. Thank you very much again

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You have plenty of $1$'s.  The problem is, where to put the $2$.  The $2$ could be in any of  the three places, or nowhere.  That gives 4 possibilities, as you've found:

111 (no twos)
112 (two in first place)
121 (two in second place)
211 (two in third place)

That's it.

Comment: what if i add another unique number to the list. how will it change the combinations?

Comment: Well, yes, now it is becoming a real problem.  How many $3$'s do you want to add?

Comment: let's say 2 3's

Comment: If you add only one $3$, then you have $3!=6$ permutations of 123, 3 permutations of 112, three permutations of 113, and one of 111.  That is 13 numbers.

Comment: If you add two 3's, you have all of these plus three permuations of 133 and three of 233 for a total of 19.

Comment: thanks for the help. was really stuck

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: if given a list of digits, I have to compute unique 3 digit numbers that can be made from that. How can I do it more like with an equation?

Comment: Well, for three digits, we can probably enumerate all the possibilities.  Each digit can only occur once, twice, or thrice.  We don't care if we have 17 ones in the bag.   We can only use 3 of them.  THis is getting long.  will use another "answer".

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a three digit number. You either use $2$ in which case you have three choices, namely $$211, 121,112$$ or you do not use $2$ in which case you only have one choice, namely $111$.

Thus you only have $4$ choices, even if the number of ones increase to more than three as long as you only have one $2$.